# How to update particular images among the images separated by comma in db

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a column which contains the image path.It can hold many images separated by comma.Its working well and fine till inserting.

The problem is when i try to update only particular image from all the images(i mean among images separated by comma) of row all inserted images of that particular row are getting updated by single image.

How can i fix this?Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is not a good design to have data separated with comma in the db column. The best way is change the db design for your image table.

Comment: explode by comma.find image you wants to update and perform Update operation

Answer (score 1):

It is bad design to have comma separated data inside a column. But, if you really want to do this extract the string. Check the code below.

```
// $text is what you use.
// Break apart at commas
$pieces = explode(",", $text);

// Use reference to be able to modify the pieces
foreach ($pieces as &$piece)
{
    $piece = wordwrap($piece, 80);
    // Modify the correct field.
}

// Join the pieces together back into one line.
$wrapped_lines = join(',', $pieces);

echo $wrapped_lines;
// You can do the database update operation here.
```

Let me know if this works..

Comment: actually what i want is like:At the user end i gave a option to upload multiple images which are being stored in a single column and this images are separated by coma like this : xxx.jpg,yyy.png,etc . But if the user what to edit this images i mean if the user wanted to update only one image say yyy.png. How can we do this? is what my question is.NOTE : user may update both the images and images are not only two we have many images.